# SoapUI maven plugin: Error: TestAssertionRegistry Missing assertion for type JsonPath Count

Tags: java, continuous-integration, automated-tests, soapui, web-api-testing

I am trying to execute SoapUI XML file using Java for Continuous Integration. My SoapUI project has JSONPath expressions as assertions. When I am executing using Java, it gives an error as follows.

```
17:37:26,465 ERROR [TestAssertionRegistry] Missing assertion for type [JsonPath RegEx Match]
17:37:26,482 ERROR [TestAssertionRegistry] Missing assertion for type [JsonPath Count]
```

I saw some people has commented on some threads that it works on SoapUI 5.2 on wards. In my pom.xml I am using the following dependency, but it don't work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to try on latest version? i.e., SoapUI 5.3 and updated plugin?

So you need to update the maven-plugin version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that haven't used for myself. 
Anyway, the above should resolve the issue.

You can refer offical maven repo location [here](http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/5.3.0/)

Comment: I have tried, but when I update the version, there are so many compile errors because some functions are deprecated in the latest version